# How can I push scattered files in github?

Tags: git

I have a github repository dedicated for userscripts. But I don't have all userscripts in the greasemonkey folder.

Similarly, I have a "Classes" repository where I paste classes made for various purposes - often just 200-300 line files.

Could I, instead of having fixed repository directory, have a list of pairs of files and their github paths?

Something like this:

```
Local path:                                  | Remote path:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\xampp\htdocs\benchmarking\Timer.class.php | PHP/Timer.class.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\jscrap\domboost.js           | JavaScript/domboost.js
C:\programing\C++\Test\Pixel.cpp             | CPP/Pixel.class.cpp
C:\programing\webprograming\canvas\Pixel.js  | JavaScript/Pixel.class.js
```

This way I could sync scatered files in one uniform repository. This would save me trouble finding and reusing them as well as serve as a good backup.

Comment: I don't think its possible with one git repo - maybe have a look at [gists](https://gist.github.com/)(your own personal pastebin) ?

Comment: Nope, I know about gists, but I'm looking for a way to keep all files up to date - in both directions.

Comment: I am not sure, whether I understand your problem... but what about git submodules?

Comment: put the stuff in a git repo and use symlinks to place them wherever